# Jquery full width slider with centered image

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Ive been trying to make one and searched google for hours, but i cannot find what im after.

Basically it is an image slider that slides in from the far right of your screen(regardless of resolution) goes to the middle of the viewport then slides out the far left.

Im not a jquery wizard so i cannot complete this myself, but i have a basic understanding how it could be done.

example: https://www.tumblr.com/

Any1 know if there is something out there that works this way?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Im half way there, it doesnt center though

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#scroller .item").css("width", $(document).width());
        $("#scroller").scrollable({
            circular: true,
            speed: 1200
        }).autoscroll({ interval: 4000, autopause: false }).navigator();
        api = $('#scroller').data("scrollable");
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($('#scroller .items:animated').length == 0) {
                $("#scroller .item").css("width", $(document).width());
                nleft = $(document).width() * (api.getIndex() + 1);
                $("#scroller .items").css("left", "-" + nleft + "px");
            }
        });
        api.onSeek(function (event) {
            $("#scroller .item").css("width", $(document).width());
            nleft = $(document).width() * (api.getIndex() + 1);
            $("#scroller .items").css("left", "-" + nleft + "px");
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML/ CSS

```
            <div id="Slider">
            <div id="area">
                <div id="scroller">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="Default.aspx" class="image"><img src="Images/Slider/1_1000x350.png" alt="" width="1140" height="350" title="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="Default.aspx" class="image"><img src="Images/Slider/2_1000x350.png" alt="" width="1140" height="350" title="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="Default.aspx" class="image"><img src="Images/Slider/3_1000x350.png" alt="" width="1140" height="350" title="" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>




 #Slider
{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:420px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#scroller 
{
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 420px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#scroller .items 
{
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:20000em;
}

#scroller .items .item {
    width: 1140px;
    height: 420px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: As i clearly said in the question, i couldnt do it myself, but i can edit in an example

Comment: you'll basically be wanting to use `.animate()` along with `.delay()`. Its a bit to much code for someone to knock up. But fingers crossed someone will know a precoded example for you.

Comment: Is it really necessery to use animate? theres no need for fancy  animations. What if i can just make a slideshow with the .slide() and slide divs with widths that is 100%, and inside them another div that is centered, inside that div the image would be.. isnt this a possible approach?

Comment: `.animate()` doesnt have to be fancy, just a transition from one position to the next.

Comment: I have a bit now, but it doesnt center, ill edit in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've managed to find what you want exactly and using it right now;
http://css-plus.com/examples/plugins/PlusSlider/

You can see full working example when you Download the slider from Github.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds exactly what I wanted to achieve.

I used [Elastislide](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/) and kind of made it fit my needs, it may be suitable for you too rather than coding from scratch?

Comment: Sort of correct, but i wanted 1 large image at the time. To much re-writing to make it work :/

Comment: Very simple to change in the options, all you have to do is set the image width and change a bit of the css, no messing around with jQuery

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you on your way:

```js
window_width = $(document).width();
window_width = window_width / 2;
element_width = $('span').width();
element_width = element_width / 2;
the_center = window_width - element_width;
$('span').animate({
  left: the_center
}, 2000).delay(1000).animate({
  left: '0'
}, 2000);
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqJXZ/)

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?